# function binding and the clone() function - Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, binding, clone

I have problems with my keyup binding when cloning an element. Here's the scenario:

I have an html markup like this:

```
<tr class="rijbasis">
   <td>
      <input type="text" class="count" />
   </td>
   <td>
       <span class="cost">10</span>
   </td>
   <td>
       <span class="total">10</span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I'm binding an keyup function to the input element of my table row like this:

```
$('.rijbasis input').keyup(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
     $('.total',parent).text(parseInt($('.cost',parent).text()) * parseInt($('.count',parent).val()));
}
```

I designed the function like this so I could clone the table row on a onclick event and append it to the tbody:

```
$('.lineadd').click(function(){
        $('.contract tbody').append($('.contract tbody tr:last').clone());
        $('.contract tbody tr:last input').val("0");
 });
```

This al works , but the keyup function doesnt work on the input elements of the cloned row..

Can anybody help or advice? I hope I was clear enough and I'll be surely adding details if needed to solve this problem.

Greetings

Comment: hehe thx :) I really love the great instant helping community here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got two *real* options

- use [`clone(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) which will also clone the bound event handlers
- use event delegation with `live()` so that the event handler is bound to a parent element and thus newly added rows will get the same functionality

Comment: Cool, did not know that! Use this one then if you're only going to clone, I think it will perform better than .live.

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery's [live events](http://api.jquery.com/live/); this way the handler will automatically be bound to newly created elements (such as the clones in your example).

For example:

```
$('.rijbasis input').live('keyup', function()
{
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    $('.total',parent).text(parseInt($('.cost',parent).text()) * parseInt($('.count',parent).val()));
}
```

Comment: I had a semi-related problem that shared the same basis of this answer.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of `.keyup`