# Clone element with events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an element:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" size="100" name="fileUpload"/>
```

A change event is bound to this element i.e. :

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function()
{
alert('changed');
});
```

I am cloning this element using:

```
var newElement = $('#fileUpload').clone();
```

and appending `newElement` to the form:

```
$('form').append(newElement);
```

Now what happens  is that after appending the change event is not bound to the new element.
Any idea why this is and how to solve this?

Comment: By reading the manual :p

Comment: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: possible duplicate of [function binding and the clone() function - Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483623/function-binding-and-the-clone-function-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var newElement = $('#fileUpload').clone(true);
```

[jQuery clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)